# Table display and the same spaces between items

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a menu with unknown items, of unknown text (language version), etc.

HTML markup is:

```css
body {margin: 0;}
menu {display: table; width: 100%; background: lightblue; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
menu li {display: table-cell;}
menu li a {display: block; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: #000; padding: 20px 0;}
```

```html
<menu>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">REFERENCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="">OUR TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
</menu>
```

Problem is, that there is biggest space around the longest item. I need to have the same spaces between all items.

I can't to set the width/padding, etc. manually, I don't know items length, count.

I attach an image with 2 situations. Space before first item and space after the last one could be smaller, but the same width (eg. these two 20px, the others 63px).

[image]

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```css
menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding:0;
    }
menu li{
        list-style:none;
        }
```

```html
<menu>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">REFERENCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="">OUR TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
</menu>
```

Comment: The justify-content property accepts 5 different values:flex-start (default), flex-end:, center:, space-between:, space-around: and space-evenly:   for more information:  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: Thanks, looks great (have never worked with flex). I've used `space-between`. The space between items has aprox. 80px, how can I get space 20px and the rest use padding for items? 80px is unknown and variable, counted padding too (due to text, number of items, etc.), 20px space between can be fixed. Is it possible? Menu width is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flex` or `grid` to achieve what you want. Using `space-evenly` might be more appropriate here.

```css
menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding:0;
    }
menu div{
   padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<menu>
    <div><a href="">HOME</a></div>
    <div><a href="">ABOUT</a></div>
    <div><a href="">REFERENCES</a></div>
    <div><a href="">OUR TEAM</a></div>
    <div><a href="">CONTACT</a></div>
</menu>
```

```css
menu{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
    grid-template-rows:2rem;
    grid-gap: auto;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding:0;
}
menu div.one {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row:1;
}
menu div.two {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row:1;
}
menu div.three {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row:1;
}
menu div.four {
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row:1;
}
menu div.five {
    grid-column: 5;
    grid-row:1;
}
```

```html
<menu>
    <div class"one"><a href="">HOME</a></div>
    <div class"two"><a href="">ABOUT</a></div>
    <div class"three"><a href="">REFERENCES</a></div>
    <div class"four"><a href="">OUR TEAM</a></div>
    <div class"five"><a href="">CONTACT</a></div>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great (have never worked with flex). I've used `space-between`. The space between items has aprox. 80px, how can I get space 20px and the rest use padding for items? 80px is unknown and variable, counted padding too (due to text, number of items, etc.), 20px space between can be fixed. Is it possible? Menu width is 100%.

Comment: @Roman, I hope i am not lost in translation... As i understand you need to set the space between to 20px. You can set 20px to `grid-gap`, if you use the `grid` solution. But there is no equivalent for `flex`.